# Check if a variable changes to true within x minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function that returns a JSON output from redis and the JSON output is below.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-09-04:54",
    "file_extension": "rpm",
    "Drive": "NAS",
    "transfer": true,
    "transfer_status_report": "Transfer successful to NAS Drive."
}
```

Now, I wanted to check if file type extension is of `rpm`, if yes, check whether the `transfer` field's value is `true` within 10 minutes,
else, timeout returning the `transfer_status_report` field's value.

How can I address the else section to re poll the redis repeatedly for 5 mins and timeout if the variable is not true by then?

Code snippet:

```
import json
import time

start_time = time.time()
timeout = 300


output_json = retrieve_status_from_redis()

while time.time() < start_time + timeout:
    if output_json["file_extension"] == "rpm":
        if output_json["transfer"] == "true":
            print(f"Transfer successful for the file")
            break
        else:
            output_json = retrieve_status_from_redis()
            #if transfer is not true within 5 minutes, 
            #timeout, printing the transfer_status_report's value.
```

Comment: @JonSG : I'm trying to print out the failed message if the time out happens, failed message as in  - `transfer_status_report`'s value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move retrieving the data into the loop, and use [`while:else:`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/compound_stmts.html#else-clause) to see whether you broke out of the loop, or if it expired on its own.

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
timeout = 300

while time.time() < start_time + timeout:
    output_json = retrieve_status_from_redis()
    if (
        output_json["file_extension"] == "rpm"
        and output_json["transfer"] == "true"
    ):
        print(f"Transfer successful for the file")
        break
    time.sleep(10)
else:
    raise TimeoutError("Oh no!")
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks.